# Matching keccak256 in RIDE and in Waves JS

Tags: javascript, wavesplatform

In my account script I want to authorize a transaction when its attachment contains a correct preimage for a keccak256 value stored in contract's data.

I use waves-crypto to calculate keccak256 of a base58 string in JS and store it in the data storage:

```js
const setDataTx = waves.data(
    {
        data: [
            { key: 'buyer', value: buyerAccount.keyPair.public },
            { key: 'seller', value: sellerAccount.keyPair.public },
            { key: 'verificationHash', value: crypto.keccak(VERIFICATION_STRING_BASE_58) },
            { key: 'blockUnlocked', value: 1000000},
        ],
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        chainId: 'T'
    },
    contractAccount.seed
);
```

I use the following predicate in my RIDE contract:

```js
sigVerify(t.bodyBytes, t.proofs[0], fromBase58String(buyerPub)) || 
        (sigVerify(tx.bodyBytes, tx.proofs[0], fromBase58String(sellerPub)) && ((lastBlock.height > blockUnlocked) || (keccak256(t.attachment) == verificationHash)))
```

I've checked all conditions except the keccak one - they all work as intended. However, the keccak condition fails. I believe it may be a format mismatch, but I'm not sure how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Keccak function](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/ride/built-in-functions/encoding-and-decoding-functions.html#keccak256), it takes an array of bytes as input parameter.

This is an example about Keccak using Waves-crypto:

```
import { keccak } from '@waves/waves-crypto'
const bytesArray = [117, 110, 99, 108, 101]
const bytesUint = Uint8Array.from([117, 110, 99, 108, 101])
const bytesBase58 = 'EFRr9cp'
keccak(bytesArray)  // 5cqz9N2PPjDkSBSwga8AttKzQEHfn8aQ95rcZZmabLA7
keccak(bytesUint)   // 5cqz9N2PPjDkSBSwga8AttKzQEHfn8aQ95rcZZmabLA7
keccak(bytesBase58) // 5cqz9N2PPjDkSBSwga8AttKzQEHfn8aQ95rcZZmabLA7
```